# What is the relation between Category theory and Graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

From my study of both these theories, they are defined differently but seem to look the same. What exactly is the main points of relation between these two fields?

Comment: Category Theory is studying relations between mathematical structures where arrows are used between the structures. Graph Theory is studying objects with relations between them given as edges, these edges can be directed or undirected, can even have multiple edges between objects. They are definitely not the same.

Comment: The arrows in category theory should be thought of as analogous to functions or relations on sets, perhaps respecting additional structure like a group homomorphism. The edges in graphs can indicate relationships like adjacency, which don't have a canonical "composition" operation.

Comment: It is true that every category gives rise to a corresponding graph, but **almost all the important information is lost in this process**. Specifically, when we just look at the "graph version" of a category, we forget the composition structure. Consider, for example, two non-isomorphic groups $G,H$ with the same cardinality. These can be thought of as categories $\mathcal{C}_G,\mathcal{C}_H$ with one object and the same number of morphisms. Meanwhile, the "graph versions" of $\mathcal{C}_G$ and $\mathcal{C}_H$ are isomorphic since $G$ and $H$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: So the similarity is in fact extremely superficial: a graph doesn't carry the same sort of algebraic structure as a category (we can't "compose edges" in a graph), and that's A Big Deal.

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber Could you please post that as answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that every category gives rise to a corresponding graph, but **almost all the important information is lost in this process**. Specifically, when we just look at the "graph version" of a category, we forget the composition structure. Consider, for example, two non-isomorphic groups $G,H$ with the same cardinality. These can be thought of as categories $\mathcal{C}_G,\mathcal{C}_H$ with one object and the same number of morphisms. Meanwhile, the "graph versions" of $\mathcal{C}_G$ and $\mathcal{C}_H$ are isomorphic since $G$ and $H$ have the same cardinality.

So the similarity is in fact extremely superficial: a graph doesn't carry the same sort of algebraic structure as a category (we can't "compose edges" in a graph), and that's A Big Deal.

---

*(In jargon, the forgetful functor from **Cats** to **Graphs** is very non-full.)*

Comment: That said, we can freely build a category by composing arrows given in a graph. In jargon, the forgetful functor from $\mathbf{Cats}$ to $\mathbf{Graphs}$ has a left adjoint. Moreover, this makes your "suprificial" similarity precise: This adjunction is [monadic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+adjunction), which means categories look like "algebras" over their underlying graphs. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264525/on-the-monadicity-of-cat), for instance.